# Visual Studio 2015: error building solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2015

I have a .Net C# solution that can be built in Visual Studio 2013 without any problem. It reference several dll's, one of them done it by me.

The problem starts when I have tried to build it in Visual Studio 2015, without doing any change (is exactly the same soultion and code). The next error (between 600 more because of this one) is shown:

```
Error metada file *.dll could not be open: invalid public key
```

I have searched a lot, but I can not find a solution for it. I would appreciate any help.

**** EDITED WITH MORE INFO ****

I use ConfuserEX. If I use the dll **before** ofuscate it, it works. The dll is not signed, so ofuscate it should not be a problem. Any ideas? (I have to ofuscate it and it have works for a long time and still works with VS2013)

Comment: have you tried to clean solution and build it again?

Comment: Is one of the assemblies signed?

Comment: The one that lauch the error is built it by me... I just built it in Release mode and reference the dll... I did not signed, but maybe it does it by default... Anyway in VS 2013 works properly...

Comment: @Ignacio Raise verbosity of your build process in VS options under "Projects and Solutions"->"Build and Run". I would set from Minimal to Detailed. Then check when does this error occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question, but for those that look here, the issue is documented as ConfuserEx issue #450:

https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/issues/450

A fix was added to the follow-on project neo-ConfuserEx, but has not been published in a release of the project (as of this writing).

https://github.com/XenocodeRCE/neo-ConfuserEx

The description of the fix is: Fix issue yck1509#450 for VS2015 and VS2017 build error when resource protection enabled (BUG: "CS0009 ... -- Invalid public key."). Which suggests you can turn off resource protection as a work-around.